# Botton webform change bootstrap class

Tags: 7, webforms, bootstrap-theme

Maybe someone knows why when you change the name of the button, its class changes from btn-primary to btn-default. btn-primary only if there is a submit in the button name (Without spaces before or after).

Comment: Because that's how the bootstrap theme is coded. There's a preprocess function which checks the button label and applies a class based on it.

Comment: Where exactly is this function implemented?

Comment: In includes/common.inc (`_bootstrap_colorize_button()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you so much for [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive) help. As it turned out, the _bootstrap_colorize_button function is responsible for choosing which class will be assigned depending on the label. To add a new word to this function, you need to implement hook_bootstrap_colorize_text_alter().
My code.

```
function myTheme_bootstrap_colorize_text_alter(array &$texts){
  $texts['contains'][t('Register')] = 'primary';
}
```

Instead of t ('Register'), you need the word and assign the bootstrap class you need.